# Python - Iterate through 2 lists at the same time

Tags: python, list, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

I have 2 lists:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c"]
m = ["x", "y", "z"]
```

And I want to iterate through both at the same time, something like this:

```
for e, f in l, m:
    print e, f
```

Must show:

```
a x
b y
c z
```

The thing is that is totally illegal. How can I do something like this? (In a Pythonic way)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) izip.  It'll look like this

```
for i,j in izip( mylistA, mylistB ):
    print i + j
```

The zip function will also work but izip creates an iterator which does not force the creation of a third list.

Comment: `zip` creates iterator in py3k